# Group a category of items based on one word in column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to group a category of items based on specific words in one column.
Example :
in column "item" I have :
wool red sweater
wool blue trousers
leather black shoes
leather brown pants

I need to categorize those items in two different categories, "wool items" and "leather items". I need to categorize several items at the same time. I think I would need regexp to extract that one specific word, but have no idea how to use it.
The query I've managed to write also returns null values, even though I am using NOTNULL + includes rows where the items are neither wool or leather.

```
    SELECT 
DISTINCT item,
       CASE WHEN item LIKE '%wool%' 
       AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL
       THEN
            1
       END AS woolitems,
       CASE WHEN item LIKE '%leather%' 
       AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL
       THEN
            1
       END AS leatheritems,
FROM   table
```

I need help understanding how to create one big category and how to have only the rows where the word I'm looking for returns. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an expected output so we can visualize how the data should be formatted?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select item, 
  regexp_extract(item, 'wool|leather') category
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 'wool red sweater' item union all
  select 'wool blue trousers' union all
  select 'leather black shoes' union all
  select 'leather brown pants' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you want to use your original query as a starting point - just wrap it up with unpivot as in below example

```
select item, category from (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT item,
    CASE 
      WHEN item LIKE '%wool%' AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL
      THEN 1
    END AS woolitems,
    CASE 
      WHEN item LIKE '%leather%' AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL
      THEN 1
    END AS leatheritems,
  FROM   your_table
)
unpivot (value for category in (woolitems, leatheritems))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This worked! But I can't manage to add other categories. I'm sorry my previous message wasn't clear. I want to add all the items that contain the word wool, lycra or cotton under the category "woolitems", but when adding more CASE WHEN, it seems like I can't put them all under the already created "woolitems" category

Comment: great! see comments to my other answer :o)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT item,
    CASE WHEN item LIKE '%wool%' 
           AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL THEN 'wool item'
        WHEN item LIKE '%leather%' 
           AND NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL THEN 'leather item'
        ELSE 'other item'
    END AS item_category
FROM `table`
```

This returns a table with 2 columns:

- item,
- item_category that will be:

  - 'wool item' if there is wool in the item name,
  - 'leather item' if there is leather in the item name,
  - 'other item' otherwise

If you want to filter out the 'other item's, you'll just have to wrap it into a CTE:

```
WITH temp AS (<previous query>)

SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE item_category != 'other item'
```

What the query you provided does is returning 3 columns:

- item,
- woolitems → 1 if there's 'wool' in item name, `NULL` otherwise
- leatheritems → 1 if there's 'leather' in item name, `NULL` otherwise

Therefore for the other items you only have NULL and NULL.